# are any boons or curses given since start of kaliyug

Tags: kali-yuga

Are any boons or curses given since start of kaliyug by sages or Gods?

Is it possible for a person to get boon by any of Gods in kaliyug?

Comment: There are no boons or curses. Duality is an illusion. The existence and live of you is alone a boon.